debian bookworm custom kernel and rootfs stuck before login prompt
I am doing the custom kernel development using debian plaform (bookworm) for the custom board.
I am able to bring up the kernel and rootfs, but I see there is no login prompt displayed asking for username.
my rootfs has "/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service" file
what might be the issue? where i need to start looking?
    [   10.234044] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-remount-fs.service - Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
    
    [   10.244663] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-udev-trigger.service - Coldplug All udev Devices...
    
    [   10.255522] systemd[1]: Mounted dev-hugepages.mount - Huge Pages File System.
    
    [   10.263155] systemd[1]: Mounted dev-mqueue.mount - POSIX Message Queue File System.
    
    [   10.271247] systemd[1]: Mounted sys-kernel-debug.mount - Kernel Debug File System.
    
    [   10.279239] systemd[1]: Mounted sys-kernel-tracing.mount - Kernel Trace File System.
    
    [   10.287404] systemd[1]: elxr-growfs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    
    [   10.296629] systemd[1]: elxr-growfs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    
    [   10.304159] systemd[1]: Failed to start elxr-growfs.service - Grow Root Filesystem.
    
    [   10.312661] systemd[1]: Finished kmod-static-nodes.service - Create List of Static Device Nodes.
    
    [   10.322213] systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Deactivated successfully.
    
    [   10.329389] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): re-mounted. Quota mode: none.
    
    [   10.329834] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@configfs.service - Load Kernel Module configfs.
    
    [   10.344879] systemd[1]: Started systemd-journald.service - Journal Service.
    
    [   10.482426] systemd-journald[278]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.

**No login prompt displayed here**

